# Drawing circles at BENDING points of convex hull

Tags: c++, opencv, convex-hull

I am trying to figure out of drawing circles at the BENDING points of a convex hull. Using the sample from [OpenCV documentation for convex hull](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html) , I have a convex hull. But I am not really sure on how to draw the circles at the points where the finger tips are which basically are the bending points for the convex hull.

I hope someone can guide me through this.

Thanks for the help

[image: ConvexHull Image]
[image: Original]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your convex hull](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull) contains points of finger tips. You can find those points by approximating with a simpler shape. You can do that with [cv::approxPolyDP](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-approxpolydp).
After that, draw circle on the points with [cvCircle, or cv::Circle](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html).